# Find and classify the singular points of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find and classify the singular point of $f(z)=\frac{z-\sin(z)}{z^4}$

---

**My attempt:**

The singular point is $z=0$

$$\lim\limits_{z\to 0}f(z)=\dots \text{Lehospital $4$ times}\dots=\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\frac{-\sin(z)}{24}=0$$

So since that the limit exists and it's final so $z=0$ is removable point

but in my book the answer is that $z=0$ is a simple pole and I can't understand way I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use l'Hopital $3$ times instead. You get $\frac{\cos z}{24z}$, which is of the form $\frac 10$ as $z \to 0$, so you're not allowed to do a fourth time.

Comment: Maybe do you know why $z=0$ is a simple pole with order $1$, I think that $z=0$ is a pole with order $4$, since that there is $z^4$

Comment: @Nehorai If you look close to the origin, the funciton looks like $\frac{z^3}{6z^4}$, which is a pole of order $1$. That is what is revealed by using l'Hopital $3$ times and getting $\frac 1{24z}$ (while keeping track of all the factorials).

Answer (score 1):

$z-\sin z=z-(z-\frac16 z^3+\cdots)=\frac16 z^3+\cdots$ and so $\frac{z-\sin z}{z^4}=\frac16\frac1z+\cdots$.

Added: I forgot to mention that it is "Hôpital".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing L'Hospital rule wrong.

$\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{z-\sin{z}}{z^4} = \lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{1 - \cos{z}}{4z^3} = \lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin{z}}{12z^2} = \lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos{z}}{24z} \neq \lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{-\sin{z}}{24}$

1/0 does not apply for L'Hospital.